# Exception at ConstructorINVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out

Tags: php, laravel, salesforce

I've been following this package : https://github.com/davispeixoto/Laravel-5-Salesforce

I know that the packages expected 4 parameters :

```
return [
    'username' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD',
    'token' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_TOKEN',
    'wsdl' => 'path/to/your/enterprise.wsdl.xml',
];
```

I'm not entirely sure, where and how do I get my token from saleforce.

---

## I've tried

create an oauth connected app in salesforce, and I have access to :

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret

---

I've tried integrating those keys in my Laravel app in my `.env`, and I kept getting

[image]

---

Did I miss anything here ? Any hints / suggestions will be a huge help !

Comment: Hate to state the obvious, but looks like one (or more) of the Salesforce auth information you provide is wrong: https://github.com/davispeixoto/Laravel-5-Salesforce/blob/master/src/Davispeixoto/Laravel5Salesforce/Salesforce.php#L39 Check the Laravels values you're passing and make sure you pass the corect info that Salesforce generated for you.

Comment: What should I put in the token ? How do I get/generate that from Saleforce ? I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. But assuming you've created a dev account on Salesforce, the API information should be available somewhere in your settings/profile.

Comment: One of my account that I got from my client, I seem **not** to be able to reset a security token. After create a new account, now I create reset a security token fine on the profile settings, and update my configuration settings in my .env file, and now, I don't get that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

One of my account that I got from my client, I seem **not** to be able to reset a security token. I don't see that option at all.

---

After create a new trail 30 days account, now I see  the `reset a security token` option on the profile settings, and update my configuration settings in my `.env` file, and now, I don't get that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything from Laravel, Salesforce, APis and Network settings, I found something about this error, basically 2 important steps to do:

1. Include the token in the password, if you are using .env vars you must to have something like this: SALESFORCE_PASSWORD=mypasswordMYTOKEN
2. active DMZ in your machine. It seems Salesforce is trying to check who is connecting throw the API, so enable DMZ option in your modem will allow you to be "visible" for Salesforce.

hope this will help anyone else, i spent too much time trying to figure out what was the solution, in my case was those two things.